# Create a Modal Dialog in Odoo Website

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-website

I did create my Modal Popup in xml and put it in `/my_module/static/src/xml/` folder

```
<t t-name="my_module.homepage_modal">
<!-- modal popup content , Signup prompt-->
</t>
```

This template is associated with a Javascript widget.
I did render it in homepage using JavaScript as follows.

```
ajax.loadXML('/my_module/static/src/xml/modal_view.xml', qweb);

var ModalPopup = Widget.extend({
    template: 'my_module.homepage_modal',

    start: function () {
        this.$el.modal();
    },
});

base.ready().done(function() {

    if (location.pathname == '/'){
        var modal1 = new ModalPopup();
        modal1.appendTo($(document.body));

    };

});`
```

I have to render this Popup only when the user is not logged in (ie Public user). How can I do this? **How can I check the current user id from JavaScript?**

Comment: Check context, there is information about current_db and user

Comment: I checked. there is nothing. It is website (odoo frontend). I am thinking about writing a controller and making a ajax call from JavaScript.

Comment: I was working on captcha so, in controller there was context with this information, so information actually exists.

Comment: In Python it is just `request.uid` . I need to access user id from JavaScript.

Comment: rly? are you kidding me? when user is not logged in you DON'T HAVE UID COZ ITS NOT EXIST IN THE WORLD, if u wanted an answer i gave you already

Comment: When user is not logged in it is `public` user, uid = 3

Comment: anyway make RPC and you will get active user

Comment: Hi @user2332665 , have you created the modal pop up?

Answer (score 0):

This is on V12.
I've used this function to check if the user is a public one (in my case, the public uid is 4):

```
function is_public_user() {
    return this.odoo.session_info.user_id == 4;
}
```

Hope this helps.
Regards